# Prove $s_n$ is a Cauchy sequence for $|s_{n+1}-s_n|\lt2^{-n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $s_n$ be a sequence and prove that it is a Cauchy sequence for $|s_{n+1}-s_n|\lt2^{-n}$

I'm not sure how to start doing this, but here's what I tried to do so based on the Cauchy sequence theorem I think i have to find an $N$ such that $n,\ n+1>N\implies |s_{n+1}-s_n|\lt2^{-n}$ but from the hypothesis it seems to be saying that all $n$ and its previous or $n-1$ are greater than $N$ and i don't think that gets me anywhere. I know there are similar posts for this problem, but i don't understand their solutions or how they approached the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $|s_{n+m}-s_n|\leq |s_{n+m}-s_{n+m-1}|+...+|s_{n+1}-s_n|\leq 2^{-(n+m-1)}+...+2^{-n}\leq {{1-({1\over 2})^m}\over {1-{1\over 2}}}{1\over {2^n}}$.